# Find both and update

Tags: c#, oop

I am trying to compare two sets and update

Comment: So what have you already tried? There are many previous questions for finding items from one list in another

Comment: So please add that code

Comment: Why did you update your question like this? Now it is very unclear what you are actually asking

Comment: Please edit the question to again contain the original question with perhaps refining what you want

Answer (score 2):

As you want to update `listB` the better thing to do is a normal `foreach` loop. Linq is not for updating but for querying. In addition consider storing `listA` as a dictionary so accessing is done in `O(1)`:

```
var a = listA.ToDictionary(k => k.Id, v => v.Price);
foreach(var item in listB)
{
    item.Price = a.TryGetValue(item.Id, out var newPrice) ? newPrice : item.Price;
}
```

Comment: @helloworld - any specific reason you want a list? This solution is an `O(n)` solution whereas with a list it will be `O(n^2)`